# I get an error when decoding jwt token, what can it be related to?

Tags: python, jwt

I write jwt authorization and an error pops up when decoding
jose.exceptions.JWTClaimsError: Subject must be a string.

I decided to check and decode the token in the same place where I encoded it, and still the error

```
async def create_access_token(self, data: dict, expires_delta: timedelta = None):
         expire = datetime.utcnow() + expires_delta if expires_delta else datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(days=3)
         encoding = data | {"exp": expire}
         encoded_jwt = jwt.encode(encoding, KEY, algorithm=ALGORITHM)
         print(encoding)
         print(encoded_jwt)
         decoded = jwt.decode(encoded_jwt, KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
         print(decoded)
         return encoded_jwt
```

How can this be fixed?

put everything into variables
I have tried converting everything to string values
checked jwt at jwt.io

Comment: [Where's the full error?](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Try and dump the variable named data, and check the type of the sub key in the dict. Sounds like the dictionary contains a value for key "sub" that is not of string type. Put the result of the dump in your question.